# Kingkiller-Chronicle Tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

I went to edit it, so was doing [some research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Kingkiller_Chronicle).  The tag [the-kingkiller-chronicles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-kingkiller-chronicles) is incorrectly named.

This is a trilogy *about* a 'chronicle' being written, non-plural.  The actual series is called 'The Kingkiller Chronicle'.  Nit-picking, I know.

Answer (score 4):

Bippity-boppity-boo!

All done.